# Same PDF file downloaded via HttpURLConnection and wget is different

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, stream

I'm downloading a PDF via Java with the following code.
After the download I can open the PDF without any error and it also has all pages but they all are blank.

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();

if(respCode == 200) {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("foo.pdf"));

    StreamUtils.copy(conn.getInputStream(), fos);

    fos.close();
}
```

If I download the PDF with a browser or wget it is completely fine.
Even the file size is exacty the same but I noticed differences when comparing the files binary.

[image: Binary Diff]

Do I have to set some encoding when writing or reading to/from the stream?

**EDIT:**
I found the error:

To be honest: The above code wasn't exactly what I was doing because I had another problem which prevented me from using some copyStream utils. So I made a workaround, which I thought is completely equivalent and posted the above code to keep it simple.

The problem: After reading the last byte instead of getting a -1 from the `read()` method I get an `IOException: Premature EOF` which seems to be a server-sided error. So instead of copying the whole stream I read it byte by byte and catch the Exception.

```
int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();

if(respCode == 200) {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    int bte = 0;
    try{
        while((bte = isr.read()) != -1) {
            zipOut.write(bte);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().equals("Premature EOF")) { // "chunked stream ended unexpectedly"
            // That's ok
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    isr.close();
}
```

The mistake I did was wrapping the `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`.

I noticed it after rading this answer [Blank PDF while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855365/blank-pdf-while-downloading?rq=1) and searched for something that "*flattens all bytes with a value higher than 127*".

The `OutputStream.write()` method said "*The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.*" but my `read()` returned values up to 65535. After that I realized that I wasn't reading from a `InputStream` but from an `InputStreamReader`...

Comment: Why are you saving it as a .txt file? Also, where are you getting StreamUtils from?

Comment: Haha, I don't. Just changed the name before posting and messed it up. The StreamUtils are from the Spring framework. But the result is the same if I write it byte by byte without a library.

Comment: Is the upper half or the lower half the correct data?

Comment: The lower half is correct.