# Blank pages in pdf after downloading it from web

Tags: java, pdf, httpclient, outputstream, writer

I am trying to download a PDF file with HttpClient, it is downloading the PDF file but pages are blank. I can see the bytes on console from response if I print them. But when I try to write it to file it is producing a blank file.

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(outputFilePath), bytes);
```

However the file is showing correct size of 103KB and 297KB as expected but its just blank!!

I tried with Output stream as well like:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
```

Also tried to write with UTF-8 coding like:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outFile), "UTF-8"));
        String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        try {
            out.write(str);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
```

Nothing is working for me. Any suggestion is highly appreciated..

Update: I am using DefaultHttpClient.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(targetURI);
HttpResponse response = null;
String htmlContents = null;
try {
    httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    InputStreamReader dataStream=new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataStream);
...
```

Comment: PDF files contain mainly binary data, so writing the file using streams won't work. What is the encoding method used for download? What are the headers provided when you download it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855365/blank-pdf-while-downloading

Comment: @BobDalgleish I added update for reference. If its not the right way, please suggest how to download PDF Files..

Comment: As I said, PDF files are mostly binary. Using a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` will corrupt the files. Check out the link by @bn4t

Comment: Thanks bob. I see the problem is corrupt file but how to download without streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do

```
InputStreamReader dataStream=new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataStream);
```

As has already been mentioned in comments, using a `Reader` class can damage binary data, e.g. PDF files. Thus, you should not wrap your content in an `InputStreamReader`.

As your content can be used to construct an `InputStreamReader`, though, I assume `response.getEntity().getContent()` returns an `InputStream`. Such an `InputStream` usually can be directly used as `IOUtils.toByteArray` argument.

So:

```
InputStream dataStream=response.getEntity().getContent();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataStream);
```

should already work for you!

Comment: This is working great for PDF files but it is corrupting the files in zip directory. Any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: That surprises me because it does not change a bit in contrast to e.g. the `Reader`-based solution in the original code. In which way is the ZIP archive corrupted? Can you simply save the `bytes` to a file and share that file for analysis? When you do so, though, please create a new stack overflow question for it (from which you can of course reference this one). It clearly is a different topic after all. But please also put a comment here to point to that new question, just in case I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I use to download a PDF file from a specific URL. The method requires two string arguments, an url string (example: `"https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRCJ_4.1.0/com.ibm.safos.doc_4.1/Planning_and_Installation.pdf"`) and a destination folder path to download the PDF file (or whatever) into. If the destination path does not exist within the local file system then it is automatically created:

```
public boolean downloadFile(String urlString, String destinationFolderPath) {
    boolean result = false; // will turn to true if download is successful
    if (!destinationFolderPath.endsWith("/") && !destinationFolderPath.endsWith("\\")) {
        destinationFolderPath+= "/";
    }
    // If the destination path does not exist then create it.
    File foldersToMake = new File(destinationFolderPath);
        if (!foldersToMake.exists()) {
            foldersToMake.mkdirs();
        }

    try {
        // Open Connection
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Get just the file Name from URL
        String fileName = new File(url.getPath()).getName();
        // Try with Resources....
        try (InputStream in = url.openStream(); FileOutputStream outStream = 
                    new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFolderPath + fileName))) {

            // Read from resource and write to file...
            int length = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer for portion of data from connection
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        // File Successfully Downloaded");
        result = true;
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    return result;
}
```