# Java - Blank PDF with HttpServlet

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using JasperReports to generate a PDF and HttpServlet to send binary data to the browser. The issue is that the generated PDF downloaded from the client side, ends up being a corrupted pdf, hence the PDF viewer displays a blank PDF.

At first, I thought it could be a JasperReports issue but I saved the PDF to a file and it worked like a charm.

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/home/user/Desktop/Example.pdf");
// jasperPrint is the rendered JasperReport
```

So it might be a problem related to HttpServlet. The way I send data is as follows:

```
    HttpServletResponse response;
    byte[] out = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint); 
    // jasperPrint is the rendered JasperReport

    response.reset();

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Example.pdf\"");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    response.setContentLength(out.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(out.length));
    response.getOutputStream().write(out, 0, out.length);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    // Right after that, the browser asks me to download the file
    // and this is the moment when I got a blank PDF
```

On top of that, I've checked this answer before I asked this question
[Blank PDF while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855365/blank-pdf-while-downloading)

One more thing: downloading a PDF works perfectly fine ( no blank PDF) on QA environment , running a JBoss Server on a Windows Machine. On my local environment I get a blank PDF as I mentioned before, running a JBoss Server on a Linux Machine.

So I was wondering : How can I check my Jboss settings to fix the problem? According to the previous question, it could be a matter of binary data that the server might be ignoring or compressing, I'm not quite sure.

Should I check out as well my web.xml file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you saved your corrupted pdf on client side and analysed it yet? Probably you find some pieces of html in front of it...

Comment: Yes I analysed and it contains question marks all over the content. I'm gona check it again just in case but I couldn't find some pieces of html

Comment: Question Marks... That sounds like at some stage your pdf is handled as text. I don't recognize that in your code excerpt, though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention an important detail: downloading a PDF works perfectly fine ( no blank PDF) on QA environment , running a JBoss Server on a Windows Machine.  On my local environment , I get a blank PDF as I mentioned before, running a JBoss Server on a Linux Machine. That why I was wondering whether this was a configuration issue or not. I'm gonna update my post with this info.

Comment: And I use Grunt to run the Server on my local environment, so it could be also an encoding issue,. Maybe a downloaded PDF via proxy is converted to a wrong encoding. It makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution! My code had nothing to do with this, it was a Grunt issue all along. For some reason, Grunt was converting the PDF sent to the browser to a wrong encoding. I had to change

**"grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0"** to     **"grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0"**.

Then I ran

**npm install**

That solved my problem. The solution was found here

https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/73#issuecomment-59532082

I can't explain why the newest version of **grunt-contrib-connect** was encoding the PDF file on a wrong way. Now I'd like to know the reason why this works.